# How to make haar cascade classifier for hand detection

Tags: computer-vision, cascade-classifier

A Classifier which detects hand in images... I am doing skin based detection for detecting hand ...

> Blockquote

"but i need that the hand would be detected without skin based color"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect without skin based color, you can train your own model with neural nets. If you don't know or how to train neural nets, I recommend that to look [Cascade Classifier Training](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html) . To train your own model with both methods, you need to hand images dataset. There are many hand dataset on the internet.

Comment: Thank you. But i used yolo for hand detection ...this is better than simple neural network for me because it also locates the hand in the picture....because i have to find the hand in the picture then used that region for classification.....for my project